# How to redefine the function that a function I import in python uses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-import

I import some module `Foo` and use a class `Foo` defined in that module. That class has function `f` which calls another function `g` that that module `Foo` itself imports from `module_with_g`. I would like to redefine the definition of `g` that `f` uses when I instantiate `Foo`. Here are 3 files which show the situation.

**Foo.py**

```
from module_with_g import g

class Foo:
    def f(self):
        x = 'bar'
        g(x)
```

**module_with_g.py**

```
def g(x):
    print(x + x)
```

**module_with_modified_Foo_f.py**

```
import Foo

def new_g(x):
    print(x + x + x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo =  Foo.Foo()
    foo.f()
```

Running the last script gives `barbar`. What I would like is to instead let `foo.f` use my own function instead of its `g` and I expect to get `barbarbar`.

My own attempt at this was to try to use a decorator to somehow redefine `foo.f`, but I haven't had any luck.

**module_with_modified_Foo_f.py**

```
import Foo

def new_g(x):
    print(x + x + x)

def redefine_f(f):
    def redefined_f(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    #redefined_f.g = new_g
    return redefined_f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo =  Foo.Foo()
    # foo.f = redefine_f(foo.f)
    # foo.__dict__['g'] = new_g # another approach
    foo.f()
```

Comment: Besides the fact, that it is dirty ;) I would try something along `Foo.g = new_g` where `Foo` is the module, not the class.

Comment: Why would you need to do that? If it's for testing, you can use [`unittest.mock.patch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch). If it's not consider redesigning your program, since changing function in runtime is one of the accepted ways to shoot yourself in the foot. ;)

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin This is so I don't need to change the actual source code of some library I am using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could do it simply, I have modified as `Foo.g = new_g` in module_with_modified_Foo_f.py

```
import Foo
def new_g(x):
    print(x + x + x)
Foo.g = new_g
if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo =  Foo.Foo()
    foo.f()
```

I got result as - `barbarbar`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want `Foo.py` to be exactly as you wrote, you can use the following as **module_with_modified_Foo_f.py**:

```
import module_with_g

def new_g(x):
    print(x + x + x)

module_with_g.g = new_g

import Foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo =  Foo.Foo()
    foo.f()
```

`Foo` doesn't reimport `module_with_g` for the second time if it already has been imported, so this can be exploited.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: Actually, I think @AlokThakur solution is cleaner and more elegant, now that I saw it. You don't need to shuffle import statements with it, so I suggest you use that instead.